# Finding out why Dell Controller is Degraded

Tags: raid, dell, snmp, dell-perc, snmpd

I installed open manage on a couple of my PE 2950s for snmp monitoring of the RAID.  All the checks seem to come back okay except for controllerState:

```
[root@aMachine ~]# snmpwalk -v 2c -c bestNotToPostPasswords myMachine -m +StorageManagement-MIB controllerstate
    StorageManagement-MIB::controllerState.1 = INTEGER: degraded(6)
```

Other checks seems to indicate the battery, LD, and physicals disks are all good unless I missing something. Can anyone tell if I am missing something or neglecting something import in my RAID monitoring/understanding? I get degraded for both these servers I have set up.

A walk of the entire storage management tree for on of them:

```
StorageManagement-MIB::softwareVersion.0 = STRING: "3.2.0"
StorageManagement-MIB::globalStatus.0 = INTEGER: warning(2)
StorageManagement-MIB::softwareManufacturer.0 = STRING: "Dell Inc."
StorageManagement-MIB::softwareProduct.0 = STRING: "Server Administrator (Storage Management)"
StorageManagement-MIB::softwareDescription.0 = STRING: "Configuration and monitoring of disk storage devices."
StorageManagement-MIB::displayName.0 = STRING: "Server Administrator (Storage Management)"
StorageManagement-MIB::description.0 = STRING: "Configuration and monitoring of disk storage devices."
StorageManagement-MIB::agentVendor.0 = STRING: "Dell Inc."
StorageManagement-MIB::agentTimeStamp.0 = INTEGER: 1273842310
StorageManagement-MIB::agentGetTimeout.0 = INTEGER: 5
StorageManagement-MIB::agentModifiers.0 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::agentRefreshRate.0 = INTEGER: 300
StorageManagement-MIB::agentMibVersion.0 = STRING: "3.2"
StorageManagement-MIB::agentManagementSoftwareURLName.0 = ""
StorageManagement-MIB::agentGlobalSystemStatus.0 = INTEGER: nonCritical(4)
StorageManagement-MIB::agentLastGlobalSystemStatus.0 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::agentSmartThermalShutdown.0 = INTEGER: notApplicable(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerName.1 = STRING: "PERC 5/i Integrated"
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerVendor.1 = STRING: "DELL"
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerType.1 = INTEGER: sas(6)
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerState.1 = INTEGER: degraded(6)
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerRebuildRateInPercent.1 = INTEGER: 30
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerFWVersion.1 = STRING: "5.0.2-0003"
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerCacheSizeInMB.1 = INTEGER: 256
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerCacheSizeInBytes.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerPhysicalDeviceCount.1 = INTEGER: 5
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerLogicalDeviceCount.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerRollUpStatus.1 = INTEGER: nonCritical(4)
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerComponentStatus.1 = INTEGER: nonCritical(4)
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerNexusID.1 = STRING: "\\0"
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerAlarmState.1 = INTEGER: disabled(2)
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerDriverVersion.1 = STRING: "00.00.03.05
"
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerPCISlot.1 = STRING: "embedded"
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerClusterMode.1 = INTEGER: notApplicable(99)
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerMinFWVersion.1 = STRING: "5.2.1-0067"
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerMinDriverVersion.1 = STRING: "00.00.03.21"
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerChannelCount.1 = INTEGER: 2
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerReconstructRate.1 = INTEGER: 30
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerPatrolReadRate.1 = INTEGER: 30
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerBGIRate.1 = INTEGER: 30
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerCheckConsistencyRate.1 = INTEGER: 30
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerPatrolReadMode.1 = INTEGER: automatic(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerPatrolReadState.1 = INTEGER: stopped(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerPatrolReadIterations.1 = INTEGER: 162
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerEntry.57.1 = INTEGER: 99
StorageManagement-MIB::controllerEntry.58.1 = INTEGER: 99
StorageManagement-MIB::channelNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::channelNumber.2 = INTEGER: 2
StorageManagement-MIB::channelName.1 = STRING: "Connector 0"
StorageManagement-MIB::channelName.2 = STRING: "Connector 1"
StorageManagement-MIB::channelState.1 = INTEGER: ready(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::channelState.2 = INTEGER: ready(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::channelRollUpStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::channelRollUpStatus.2 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::channelComponentStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::channelComponentStatus.2 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::channelNexusID.1 = STRING: "\\0\\0"
StorageManagement-MIB::channelNexusID.2 = STRING: "\\0\\1"
StorageManagement-MIB::channelBusType.1 = INTEGER: sas(8)
StorageManagement-MIB::channelBusType.2 = INTEGER: sas(8)
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureName.1 = STRING: "Backplane"
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureVendor.1 = STRING: "DELL"
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureState.1 = INTEGER: ready(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureProductID.1 = STRING: "BACKPLANE       "
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureType.1 = INTEGER: internal(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureChannelNumber.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureRollUpStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureComponentStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureNexusID.1 = STRING: "\\0\\0\\0"
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureFirmwareVersion.1 = STRING: "1.00"
StorageManagement-MIB::enclosureSASAddress.1 = STRING: "50019090B4C67200"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskNumber.2 = INTEGER: 2
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskNumber.3 = INTEGER: 3
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskNumber.4 = INTEGER: 4
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskName.1 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskName.2 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:1"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskName.3 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:2"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskName.4 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:3"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskVendor.1 = STRING: "DELL    "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskVendor.2 = STRING: "DELL    "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskVendor.3 = STRING: "DELL    "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskVendor.4 = STRING: "DELL    "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskState.1 = INTEGER: online(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskState.2 = INTEGER: online(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskState.3 = INTEGER: online(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskState.4 = INTEGER: online(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskProductID.1 = STRING: "ST3146755SS     "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskProductID.2 = STRING: "ST3146755SS     "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskProductID.3 = STRING: "ST3146755SS     "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskProductID.4 = STRING: "ST3146755SS     "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSerialNo.1 = STRING: "3LN0LRL0            "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSerialNo.2 = STRING: "3LN0JYJS            "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSerialNo.3 = STRING: "3LN0LR0V            "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSerialNo.4 = STRING: "3LN0JH97            "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskRevision.1 = STRING: "T106"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskRevision.2 = STRING: "T106"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskRevision.3 = STRING: "T106"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskRevision.4 = STRING: "T106"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureID.1 = STRING: "0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureID.2 = STRING: "0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureID.3 = STRING: "0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureID.4 = STRING: "0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskChannel.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskChannel.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskChannel.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskChannel.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLengthInMB.1 = INTEGER: 139392
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLengthInMB.2 = INTEGER: 139392
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLengthInMB.3 = INTEGER: 139392
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLengthInMB.4 = INTEGER: 139392
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLengthInBytes.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLengthInBytes.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLengthInBytes.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLengthInBytes.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLargestContiguousFreeSpaceInMB.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLargestContiguousFreeSpaceInMB.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLargestContiguousFreeSpaceInMB.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLargestContiguousFreeSpaceInMB.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLargestContiguousFreeSpaceInBytes.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLargestContiguousFreeSpaceInBytes.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLargestContiguousFreeSpaceInBytes.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLargestContiguousFreeSpaceInBytes.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskTargetID.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskTargetID.2 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskTargetID.3 = INTEGER: 2
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskTargetID.4 = INTEGER: 3
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLunID.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLunID.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLunID.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLunID.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskUsedSpaceInMB.1 = INTEGER: 139392
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskUsedSpaceInMB.2 = INTEGER: 139392
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskUsedSpaceInMB.3 = INTEGER: 139392
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskUsedSpaceInMB.4 = INTEGER: 139392
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskUsedSpaceInBytes.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskUsedSpaceInBytes.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskUsedSpaceInBytes.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskUsedSpaceInBytes.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskFreeSpaceInMB.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskFreeSpaceInMB.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskFreeSpaceInMB.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskFreeSpaceInMB.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskFreeSpaceInBytes.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskFreeSpaceInBytes.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskFreeSpaceInBytes.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskFreeSpaceInBytes.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskBusType.1 = INTEGER: sas(8)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskBusType.2 = INTEGER: sas(8)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskBusType.3 = INTEGER: sas(8)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskBusType.4 = INTEGER: sas(8)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSpareState.1 = INTEGER: notASpare(5)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSpareState.2 = INTEGER: notASpare(5)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSpareState.3 = INTEGER: notASpare(5)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSpareState.4 = INTEGER: notASpare(5)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskRollUpStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskRollUpStatus.2 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskRollUpStatus.3 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskRollUpStatus.4 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskComponentStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskComponentStatus.2 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskComponentStatus.3 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskComponentStatus.4 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskNexusID.1 = STRING: "\\0\\0\\0\\0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskNexusID.2 = STRING: "\\0\\0\\0\\1"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskNexusID.3 = STRING: "\\0\\0\\0\\2"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskNexusID.4 = STRING: "\\0\\0\\0\\3"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskPartNumber.1 = STRING: "SG0DR2381253172FLRL0A00 "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskPartNumber.2 = STRING: "SG0DR2381253172FJYJSA00 "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskPartNumber.3 = STRING: "SG0DR2381253172FLR0VA00 "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskPartNumber.4 = STRING: "SG0DR2381253172FJH97A00 "
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSASAddress.1 = STRING: "5000C50002380201"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSASAddress.2 = STRING: "5000C50002385B89"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSASAddress.3 = STRING: "5000C50002385AA9"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSASAddress.4 = STRING: "5000C500023841E1"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSmartAlertIndication.1 = INTEGER: no(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSmartAlertIndication.2 = INTEGER: no(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSmartAlertIndication.3 = INTEGER: no(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskSmartAlertIndication.4 = INTEGER: no(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureDay.1 = STRING: "07"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureDay.2 = STRING: "07"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureDay.3 = STRING: "07"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureDay.4 = STRING: "07"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureWeek.1 = STRING: "07"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureWeek.2 = STRING: "07"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureWeek.3 = STRING: "07"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureWeek.4 = STRING: "07"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureYear.1 = STRING: "2005"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureYear.2 = STRING: "2005"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureYear.3 = STRING: "2005"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskManufactureYear.4 = STRING: "2005"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskMediaType.1 = INTEGER: hdd(2)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskMediaType.2 = INTEGER: hdd(2)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskMediaType.3 = INTEGER: hdd(2)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskMediaType.4 = INTEGER: hdd(2)
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.36.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.36.2 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.36.3 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.36.4 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.40.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.40.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.40.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.40.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.41.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.41.2 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.41.3 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEntry.41.4 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionNumber.2 = INTEGER: 2
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionNumber.3 = INTEGER: 3
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionNumber.4 = INTEGER: 4
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionArrayDiskName.1 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionArrayDiskName.2 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:1"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionArrayDiskName.3 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:2"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionArrayDiskName.4 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:3"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionArrayDiskNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionArrayDiskNumber.2 = INTEGER: 2
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionArrayDiskNumber.3 = INTEGER: 3
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionArrayDiskNumber.4 = INTEGER: 4
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionEnclosureName.1 = STRING: "Backplane"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionEnclosureName.2 = STRING: "Backplane"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionEnclosureName.3 = STRING: "Backplane"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionEnclosureName.4 = STRING: "Backplane"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionEnclosureNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionEnclosureNumber.2 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionEnclosureNumber.3 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionEnclosureNumber.4 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionControllerName.1 = STRING: "PERC 5/i Integrated"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionControllerName.2 = STRING: "PERC 5/i Integrated"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionControllerName.3 = STRING: "PERC 5/i Integrated"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionControllerName.4 = STRING: "PERC 5/i Integrated"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionControllerNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionControllerNumber.2 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionControllerNumber.3 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskEnclosureConnectionControllerNumber.4 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryName.1 = STRING: "Battery 0"
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryVendor.1 = STRING: "DELL"
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryState.1 = INTEGER: ready(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryRollUpStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryComponentStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryNexusID.1 = STRING: "\\0\\0"
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryPredictedCapacity.1 = INTEGER: ready(2)
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryNextLearnTime.1 = INTEGER: 21
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryLearnState.1 = INTEGER: idle(16)
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryEntry.13.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryMaxLearnDelay.1 = INTEGER: 168
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryConnectionNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryConnectionBatteryName.1 = STRING: "Battery 0"
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryConnectionBatteryNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryConnectionControllerName.1 = STRING: "PERC 5/i Integrated"
StorageManagement-MIB::batteryConnectionControllerNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskName.1 = STRING: "Virtual Disk 0"
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskDeviceName.1 = STRING: "/dev/sda"
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskState.1 = INTEGER: ready(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskLengthInMB.1 = INTEGER: 278784
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskLengthInBytes.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskWritePolicy.1 = INTEGER: writeBack(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskReadPolicy.1 = INTEGER: noReadAhead(5)
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskCachePolicy.1 = INTEGER: not-applicable(99)
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskLayout.1 = INTEGER: raid-10(10)
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskCurStripeSizeInMB.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskCurStripeSizeInBytes.1 = INTEGER: 65536
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskTargetID.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskRollUpStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskComponentStatus.1 = INTEGER: ok(3)
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskNexusID.1 = STRING: "\\0\\0"
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskArrayDiskType.1 = INTEGER: sas(1)
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskEntry.23.1 = INTEGER: 2
StorageManagement-MIB::virtualDiskEntry.24.1 = INTEGER: 0
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionNumber.2 = INTEGER: 2
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionNumber.3 = INTEGER: 3
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionNumber.4 = INTEGER: 4
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionArrayDiskName.1 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionArrayDiskName.2 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:1"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionArrayDiskName.3 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:2"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionArrayDiskName.4 = STRING: "Physical Disk 0:0:3"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionArrayDiskNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionArrayDiskNumber.2 = INTEGER: 2
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionArrayDiskNumber.3 = INTEGER: 3
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionArrayDiskNumber.4 = INTEGER: 4
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionVirtualDiskName.1 = STRING: "Virtual Disk 0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionVirtualDiskName.2 = STRING: "Virtual Disk 0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionVirtualDiskName.3 = STRING: "Virtual Disk 0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionVirtualDiskName.4 = STRING: "Virtual Disk 0"
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionVirtualDiskNumber.1 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionVirtualDiskNumber.2 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionVirtualDiskNumber.3 = INTEGER: 1
StorageManagement-MIB::arrayDiskLogicalConnectionVirtualDiskNumber.4 = INTEGER: 1
```

**Update in Response To Battery Question:**
Not entirely sure about the age, a few years?  Maybe this helps:

```
[root@aMachine ~]# /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli -AdpBbuCmd  -aALL

BBU status for Adapter: 0

BatteryType: BBU
Voltage: 4054 mV
Current: 0 mA
Temperature: 10 C
Firmware Status: 00000000

Battery state: 

GasGuageStatus:
  Fully Discharged        : No
  Fully Charged           : Yes
  Discharging             : Yes
  Initialized             : Yes
  Remaining Time Alarm    : No
  Remaining Capacity Alarm: No
  Discharge Terminated    : No
  Over Temperature        : No
  Charging Terminated     : No
  Over Charged            : No

Relative State of Charge: 100 %
Charger Status: Complete
Remaining Capacity: 1472 mAh
Full Charge Capacity: 1478 mAh
isSOHGood: Yes

BBU Capacity Info for Adapter: 0

Relative State of Charge: 100 %
Absolute State of charge: 77 %
Remaining Capacity: 1472 mAh
Full Charge Capacity: 1478 mAh
Run time to empty: 65535 Min
Average time to empty: 65535 Min
Average Time to full: 65535 Min
Cycle Count: 15
Max Error: 2 %
Remaining Capacity Alarm: 190 mAh
Remaining Time Alarm: 10 Min


BBU Design Info for Adapter: 0

Date of Manufacture: 01/09, 2007
Design Capacity: 1900 mAh
Design Voltage: 3700 mV
Specification Info: 8000
Serial Number: 2991
Pack Stat Configuration: 0xe49c
Manufacture Name: SMP-PA
Device Name: X848371
Device Chemistry: LION


BBU Properties for Adapter: 0

Auto Learn Period: 7776000 Sec
Next Learn time: 327149518 Sec 
Learn Delay Interval:0 Hours
Auto-Learn Mode: Enabled
```

**Update 2, this is just to go for a question length record:**
Hmm..
One of the two it turns out that the battery is about to start this process on its own.  However, this doesn't seem to be the case on the other one.  So I am thinking it is something else?

```
/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli -FwTermLog -Dsply -aALL
...
05/08/10  3:40:18: Next PR scheduled to start at 05/15/10  3:00:00
05/10/10 10:52:14: EVT#08474-05/10/10 10:52:14: 157=Battery relearn will start in 4 days
05/12/10 10:52:49: EVT#08475-05/12/10 10:52:49: 158=Battery relearn will start in 2 day
05/13/10 10:52:34: EVT#08476-05/13/10 10:52:34: 159=Battery relearn will start in 1 day
05/13/10 15:43:08: EVT#08477-05/13/10 15:43:08:  73=VD 00/0 Properties updated to [ID=00,dcp=01,ccp=01,ap=0,dc=0,dbgi=0] (from [ID=00,dcp=01,ccp=01,ap=0,dc=0,dbgi=0])
05/13/10 13:30:22: EVT#08478-05/13/10 13:30:22:  44=Time established as 05/13/10 13:30:22; (5228737 seconds since power on)
05/13/10 13:30:24: EVT#08479-05/13/10 13:30:24:  30=Event log cleared
05/13/10 13:30:54: EVT#08480-05/13/10 13:30:54:  30=Event log cleared
05/13/10 13:31:12: EVT#08481-05/13/10 13:31:12:  30=Event log cleared
05/13/10 13:31:31: EVT#08482-05/13/10 13:31:31:  30=Event log cleared
05/14/10  5:52:43: EVT#08483-05/14/10  5:52:43: 160=Battery relearn will start in 5 hours
```

Comment: I should also mention that `/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LDInfo -Lall -aALL` reuturns optimal on both servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller state requires that both the Controller Firmware and the kernel module (driver) be up to date.  Once I updated both of those the controller state changed to "Ready."

Answer (score 1):

How old is your server?
In the dell docs, the degraded state of the controller means that the battery should be reconditioned. Normally this is done automatically, but if too old then you need to change it.

PS: if you have openmanage installed, there's somewhere a option to manually recondition the battery. Be careful because that task takes about 8-10 hours and in that time the battery is discharged and recharged.

Comment: Updated my question with more battery info.

Comment: Looking at that report it doesn't look bad.
The year should be 2007 so, yes, about 3 years.
Anyway the reconditioning should be available only for NiMHi batteries and your is LION.
As dyasny suggested, try to replace the battery with another one, if you have another one.

Comment: Calling now, but that reminded me of a third reason, the crap muzak I have to listen to ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As I keep telling people here - why rely on online support, when you can call the vendor support? 
With Dell this sort of question is resolved right on the spot, with minimal work on your part.

Having said that, what I'd do is reseat the BBU, and if possible swap it out with another from the other PE9250s you have. If that doesn't help, you might need a replacement.

Comment: dynasy:  I was planning on calling them if I don't get resolved.  But a couple of reasons I like to start here is that often it is faster.  Secondly, then the information will get indexed in Google and possibly save someone else the same call.

Comment: In my experience, calling support is faster, and if you want the solution to be known, blog about it (that's what I usually do)

From my own experience in Dell support, there was a bunch of BBU's shipped that spent a bit too long in storage, and would fail very quickly. Once a call about those came in, the tech usually dispatched a replacement battery right away, no extra troubleshooting. Maybe you've got one of those, but only the support guys would be able to say for sure

Comment: -1 to dynasy's comment because years down the road, working with older out-of-support hardware, q & a like this is very helpful. +1 to Kyle Brandt because he's right on the money. Here it is, 6 years later, and a Google search led me right to this webpage. His reasoning is not only sound, it saves a lot of time (support calls in my experience sometimes take an hour to get to the same conclusion I can reach in 10 minutes online).

Comment: @MikeS PE2950 came out in 2007, which makes it 9 years old today. My answer was provided in 2010, while it was still not EOL. If you go through serverfault and -1 all the answers that lost their relevance in the timespan of 6 years, you'll have a full time job for a very long time. Oh, and BTW, as someone who used to work at Dell server support, even if you call in about EOL hardware, they will try to help with troubleshooting, even if they will not replace parts for you, so calling them may still be useful even for a 9 year old machine.

Comment: @dyasny -1 for missing my whole point, which is: People are more than welcome to post their questions here, even for supported hardware/software, because there are very good reasons to do so- as evidenced by my good forture to come upon this question years later that has relevance to me. Stating your timeline misses my point entirely. Furthermore, I've often found the support and answers here are often better than the vendors, because your support call may be answered by a college freshout reading from a troubleshooting guide. Here, you bump into IT guys with 20 years' experience.

Comment: @MikeS You miss the whole point of this site, and I do not appreciate the condescending tone either. You have just bumped into an "IT guy with 20 years' experience" right here, and he tells you the advice to talk to a vendor for brandname hardware is valid and works. Downvoting is for wrong and misleading answers, not for what __you__ consider a worse solution than others. Besides, a collee grad working at Dell has a quality lead who has those same 20 years of experience, plus a lot of internal tools and information available to him.

Comment: You're right, I should not have downvoted. Although I don't like your advice, I was wrong to downvote. I appreciate the education.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the DSM services.  It's a disconnect between the PERC and the OpenManage.  Usually after an array rebuilds but it doesn't update this.